# Create a generic shape and draw it as a polygon with center (or base) and rotation?

Tags: geometry, jts-topology-suite

In Java (jts), is there a way to draw a generic shape, eg. bounded in meters, and apply this to a coordinate, with rotation around a center or base?

Something like:

```
double lat = 65.100
double lon = 7.123
Box box = new Box(10, 100, METERS);
Rectangle rect = 
    GeometricShapeFactory.createRectangle(box, lat, lon, Math.toRadians(45));
```

where lat and lon are coordinates in WGS84

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the OpenJUMP Jython tool "Rotated Rectangle Tool" can give some inspiration. Code is so short that I copy it all here:

```
# Copyright (C) 2005 Integrated Systems Analysts, Inc.
# This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
# modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Coordinate as Coordinate
import org.openjump.util.python.pythonexampleclasses.DrawCustomTool.FinalDrawListener as FinalDrawListener
from com.vividsolutions.jts.algorithm.CGAlgorithms import * 
import org.openjump.core.geomutils.GeoUtils as GeoUtils


class ToolListener(FinalDrawListener):
    def finalDraw(self, event):
        p = event.coords
        dist = distancePointLinePerpendicular(p[2], p[0], p[1])
        toLeft = computeOrientation(p[1], p[0], p[2]) == LEFT
        p[2] = GeoUtils.perpendicularVector(p[1], p[0], dist, toLeft)
        p.add(GeoUtils.vectorAdd(p[2], GeoUtils.vectorBetween(p[1], p[0]) ))
        #p.add(CoordUtils.add(p[2], CoordUtils.subtract(p[1], p[0]) )) #jts way
        p.add(Coordinate(p[0]))
        width = p[0].distance(p[1])
        length = p[1].distance(p[2])
        panel = event.wc.layerViewPanel
        statMsg = "[" + panel.format(width) + ", " + panel.format(length) + "]"
        event.statusMessage = statMsg
```

Comment: Yes, but this seems to assume that you actually have the coordinates of ll, lr, ur and ul. I would like to hide this behind some abstraction.

Comment: As I said, it was for giving some inspiration. Perhaps native OpenJUMP sources please you more. By the name this perhaps rotates something http://sourceforge.net/p/jump-pilot/code/HEAD/tree/core/trunk/src/com/vividsolutions/jump/plugin/edit/TwoPointTransRotScaleBuilder.java

Comment: Yes, thank you. Rotation, although, is just a part of the problem. The essence is applying a geometry of some coordinate system to a point in another. Rotation can always be solved by applying simple geometrics to the first mentioned geometry.

Comment: JTS can read WKT. If you want a rectangle with lower left corner at x,y, build it as `POLYGON ((x y,x+1 y,x+1 y+1,x y+1,x xy))`. Once it is created, rotate it. Is this what you want?

Comment: WKT assumes WGS84, doesn't it? What I want is similar to OpenMap's `new LatLonPoint(y, x).getPoint(Length.METER.toRadians(meters), Math.toRadians(azimuth))`

Comment: WKT does not assume anything about projections, neither does JTS. Coordinates are just numbers for them.

Comment: Yes, but still, this polygon will eventually have to be applied to a WGS84 system in my case. The "metric" polygon is being checked against a series of polygons defined in WGS84.

Comment: Edit your question accordingly. As far as I know you can't do that with JTS alone but you will need to use some projection library as well. Geotools, deegree or something else.

Comment: Yes, I'm perfectly able to do it with OpenMap, but since the developers refuse to publish the library properly, it makes the dependency management a mess. Clarified the question, thanks for pinpointing.